How to supply solrConnectionString when deploying Sitecore 10.3.1 to Azure?
I created a VM and installed the Solr 8.11 and added public IP address and certificate to make Solr accessible from outside the VM as https://mydomain.com:8983/solr - url tested and it is working.
I set the parameter solrConnectionString to https://mydomain.com:8983/solr, I got the following error:
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment : 3:51:08 AM - The deployment 'sitecore1031' failed with error(s). Showing 3 out of 3 error(s).
Status Message: ARM-MSDeploy Deploy Failed: 'Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentXmlException: 

The declared parameter 'Search SOLR Core Application Connection String' is not recognized.
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncParameterCollection.LoadFromFile(XPathNavigator nav, String fileName, Boolean ignoreExtraSetParameters)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.AppGalleryPackage.LoadSetParameters(DeploymentObject deploymentObject, IDictionary`2 setParams, String setParamXmlFile) in 
C:\__w\1\s\src\hosting\wdeploy\Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi\AppGalleryPackage.cs:line 523

What could be the problem? anyone successfully deploy Azure 10.x to Azure using solr?
Thank you very much!

Solr Search configuration should have following settings:
"xcSearchMsDeployPackageUrl": { "value": "https://XXXXX.blob.core.windows.net/storage/WDP/XP/Sitecore 9.2.0 rev. 002893 (Cloud)_xp1collectionsearchSOLR.scwdp.zip" }

It should include namespace as _xp1collectionsearchSOLR.
Hope this helps!!!
